# How to show only group in ui-grid , rather than having separate column in grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

In ui-grid for grouping column, there are some examples , but all thoose having separete columns for grouping. i saw below example

[Any better approaches in achieving multi-column grouping in UI-Grid header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564283/any-better-approaches-in-achieving-multi-column-grouping-in-ui-grid-header)

But in this, there is merchant column is presented as separately , and showing same name for all rows , which I don't need , the "MERCHANT" group header should show in NAME column only. I tried with "visible: false" in this case it is showing groups but not showing group name. I have shown what I need in below image.

[image]

Note: same I have achieved with jquery jg-grid. But in angular I am not able to :(

Answer (score 1):

Set width of grouped column to 1 pixel.

And for grouping row set overflow to visible, but for content row keep overflow at its default value.